# Java: thread-local properties - why do they increase heap usage and GC activity instead of decreasing it?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, heap-memory, thread-local

I'm running an async task (defined in a method annotated with Spring's @Async annotation) on multiple parallel threads in a Spring Boot application. I use a ThreadPoolExecutor to manage threads, which is initialised with a ThreadPoolExecutorFactoryBean:

```
    @Bean
    ThreadPoolExecutorFactoryBean myThreadPoolExecutor() {

        final ThreadPoolExecutorFactoryBean factoryBean = new ThreadPoolExecutorFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setCorePoolSize(...);
        factoryBean.setMaxPoolSize(...);
        factoryBean.setQueueCapacity(...);
        factoryBean.setKeepAliveSeconds(...);
        factoryBean.setPrestartAllCoreThreads(true);
        factoryBean.setAllowCoreThreadTimeOut(false);
        factoryBean.setExposeUnconfigurableExecutor(true);
        return factoryBean;
    }
```

The task uses a ByteBuffer inside. This buffer used to be defined as a local variable in the async method before.

As the app is memory-critical, I'd like to decrease the heap usage of the threads as much as possible, so I try to "recycle" the spaces once allocated.

To achieve this, I introduced a thread-local property for the ByteBuffer (among some other previously local variables) in the @Component where the @Async method is defined:

```
private ThreadLocal<ByteBuffer> buffer;
```

This thread-local property gets initialised in the @Component's constructor, where I allocate space for the buffer:

```
public MyComponent(...) {
    ...
    this.buffer = ThreadLocal.withInitial(() -> ByteBuffer.allocate(2048));
    ...
}
```

This way we have to allocate buffer space only once, and the successive tasks received by the same thread should use the same space for their calculations, instead of allocating a new buffer as a local variable every time the thread receives a new task from the ThreadPoolExecutor. And as each thread has its own value of the thread-local property (maintained in its thread-local map), this solution should be thread-safe, the multiple parallel-running threads won't mess up the data in each other's buffer. (The task's code is implemented in such a way that the data written into the buffer by a previous run on the same thread, doesn't effect the current run; the async task just needs a buffer space for counting, it's not a problem for it if the buffer space already contains data from a previous run, it will rewrite it anyway. So the successive runs on the same thread don't disturb each other, either.)

I read about that thread-local properties can cause a memory leak if they are not .remove()-d, because the thread-local property holds a strong reference to them. However, here, all threads in the thread pool are working continuously until the moment they die, and even their death happens very rarely (usually only when the app terminates itself). Once the threads finish the execution of one task, they will shortly receive a new one from the executor service. In this app, the threads and their thread-local properties are designed for life-long continuous usage.

From introducing thread-local properties, we hoped decreased heap usage and GC activity. But we experience the opposite, and this is the question of the post: both heap usage & minor GC collection count and time increased after deploying this change.

I've made heap dumps, and they tell that the thread-local space does get deallocated after a thread's potential death. And debugger proved that the same buffer object is indeed kept and shared between successive tasks executed by a certain thread.

I've been digging into the underlying code for a few days now, to find a root cause why it behaves this way, but I've not found any explanation yet. I once supposed "it might be because the thread-local properties might get created on the main thread instead of the worker threads", but this assumption proved wrong - they are rightfully created on each worker thread, as expected -, and in the moment, I have no further idea where else to look, what direction I should dig into even deeper. :(

Does anyone have any idea how to explain this anomaly (why thread-locals work opposite from what we would expect, why they increase heap usage and GC activity instead of decreasing it in comparison to having a local buffer variable defined in the async method)?...

Comment: This is pretty normal, and the reason is that the GC is really good at its job and allocating objects and quickly discarding them is exactly what the GC is optimized for.

Comment: @LouisWasserman, the question is why this happens here - that there are new objects allocated and then discarded -, while the code with the thread-locals should provide (according to my intention and understanding) that there should be object creation only at thread startup, and then later the existing objects should be recycled. Which part of my thread-local code does this in your opinion, that it creates a lot of new objects and then lets them be discarded by GC?...

Comment: Are `MyComponent` instances even shared between threads?

Comment: @Holger since this is a Spring `@Component`, its almost for sure, a single instance per app (Spring container).

Comment: this is somehow confusing (only the Spring wiring part). If you have your `ByteBuffer` inside the `@Component` constructor - which is a singleton, then how is any sharing supposed to happen between threads? I am confused, or you need to explain that part.

Comment: @BresalioNagy: I'm claiming that your thread-local code _doesn't_ do that, and that if you didn't use a thread-local, but allocated a fresh `ByteBuffer` every time, it'd be better.